# What can explain this bad character-encoding?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

What "stack" of bad encoding would produce the following bytes of weirdness for the string "cinéma télédiffusion"? (I left out the space character, hex: 20)

```
cinÃ%ma
in HEX: 63 69 6E C3 83 25 6D 61
mapped: c  i  n  ---�----  m  a

tÃclÃcdiffusion
in HEX: 74 C3 83 63 6C C3 83 63 64 69 66 66 75 73 69 6F 6E
mapped: t  ---�---- l  ---�---- d  i  f  f  u  s  i  o  n
```

The ---�---- parts represent the bytes that aren't right.

I considered the idea "What if it was a messed up transcoding? How about a double encoding?", but, looking at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/charset_support.htm (and the code page edition, too), I noted that there no encodings that could possibly end é with the hex bytes %25 or %63. It doesn't even look like double-UTF8 encoding at this point, because, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 clarified that bytes following a %C3 would need to be have the first bits set to 10xxxxxx.

How could some program have turned the accented **é** into an "**Ã** followed by **%**" as well as "**Ã** followed by **c**"? I want to trace back the history of the misencoding so that I can try to come up with something that can take steps at repairing the mangled strings.

There also exists the possibility that the **é** weren't ever **é** to begin with, but I can't fathom what kind of typo someone could have made in the same phrase to get two different versions of **é** that eventually get misencoded into two completely different sets of bytes.

Extra context details: I find these mangled strings inside of an XML file. The file has no **<?xml version="1.0"?>** header, so it's presumed to be UTF-8. There exists nodes containing phrases that have perfectly good **é** characters in them at the same time that there exists nodes containing phrases with mangled **é** characters.

*iconv*-and-family don't do anything at all to help this situation, as far as I've attempted.

A couple of trailing considerations that I now hold are: Should I suspect MySQL and its infamously lazy character set transcodings? Could it be somebody's really badly written custom encoding function as they exported the XML?

Comment: It was definitely utf-8 encoded twice.  There was a mystery code page encoding in between.  Different ones.  One turned © in c.  The other is hard to guess.  Send that xml file back, you don't want it.

Comment: It's weird that the same character gets converted to different bytes in different words.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is ever going to be recoverable. Sorry! There is definitely a double-UTF-8 in there somewhere, but non-deterministic mangling that spits out ASCII for the second character is neither a common nor a remediable corruption.

Comment: The insights have brought clarity and I'm thankful for that. I originally meant "it doesn't look like -the usual, recoverable- double UTF8 encode".  I love how the funky, double-encode was described as "Send that xml file back, you don't want it." :) Technically, I feel like my question answered already... Dunno what to do about the empty "Answers" section.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding looks a bit strange:

Taken the é from cinéma results in for utf-8 encoding:

> é = C3 A9

where you got:

> C3 83 25

So when it will be double encoded the following should happen:

> c3: Ã -> c3 83
>
> a9: © -> c2 a9

But this will not explain the 25 within your result.

> 25: %

So the question is if this is encode once, then unknown characters like © will be replaced by % and then it's encoded a second time?

Comment: The whole string of two words got mangled in different ways around the accented "e". In each case of "mangling", extra characters appeared: "%" (hex 25) in the first case and "c" (hex 63) in the latter two. I think the exact stack of double-encodes and code-pages and lost-in-encoding will remain at large for quite some time to come.

I'd suspect that the bytes are getting wrecked amongst MySQL's schemes for "ASCII, 3-byte UTF8 and full UTF8" and various programming languages' "ASCII and UTF8" strings.

Comment: Just for information: UTF-8  is (depending on the used characters) always a 1-4 byte encoding. - So there is no 3-byte UTF-8 compared to "full" UTF-8 - for more please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
Also from my example above I haven't seen any valid UTF-8 3 byte code during the double encode of the é. So there must be something more than only double encoding. Whats also strange is that the é results into different bytes for cinéma and for télédiffusion.